# What would you like to know about Hermeneutics.SE?

Tags: discussion

What would you like to know about the questions or answers posted on this site? I've just happened upon the API and am planning on doing some analysis of our questions, comments, and answers. Additionally, we could generate some site evals for BH.SE as opposed to a Google search.

So, what metrics/data/information/knowledge would be interesting or useful?

Comment: [Beta sites are now available in the data explorer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216245/147191).

Answer (score 3):

- I'd like to know the view/vote ratio on BH compared to other sites, including SO.

  I've got the impression that people don't vote as often here as they do on other sites.  But this is probably the smallest site I frequent.  So it would be helpful to know roughly how many views turned into votes (up or down) on our site compared to others.
- You already [know this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5215124#5215124), but I'd like to index all of our questions by chapter and verse.
- If we want, I can request from the dev team a list of 10 non-negative, open questions with at least one answer from 30 to 40 days ago (which is the SE standard) to use as a self-evaluation.  But if we did it ourselves, that would be simpler.
- I don't know if it's possible, but I'd like to know the best time of day to have a chat event (a town hall meeting in chat) to maximize participation.  [Quantcast](http://www.quantcast.com/hermeneutics.stackexchange.com) suggests sometime on Wednesday, but I'd like to know what hour is best.
- Some version of the [active users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103247/1438) metric would be very helpful.

If I think of more, I'll add them.  But please take this list as low-priority and focus on what seems most interesting to you.

And thank you!